# where clause between two columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a specific question about query builder. I'm creating something to make tournaments.

I have a model Match which have columns player_one and player_two. I would like to know if the match between these two players already exist.

To instance,a player have id 1 and an other player have id 2, if one row have player_one = 1 and player_two = 2 : the match already exist but if  player_one = 2 and player_two = 1 : **the match exist too.**

Sorry for my english, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should look into [orWhere()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) , maybe:

```
 Matches::where(function($query) {
                $query->whereIn('player_1', $first_value)
                    ->orWhereIn('player_1', $second_value);
            })->where(function($query) {
                $query->whereIn('player_2', $second_value)
                    ->orWhereIn('player_2', $first_value);
            })->first();
```

Comment: I'm so glad. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.